# Custom has-error styling class in angular-formly

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

I'm new to js/html so I'm actually not sure if it's angular-formly specific. I can't figure out how to change the css style globally (or for a single field) when a field is invalid. Does someone know how to do it or where I can find documentation about it? All documention I find uses the default has-error class.

Comment: Can you share your code, what have you tried so far? thx

Comment: Nvm I just figured out that this is done with wrappers. Anyway I was just looking for the documentation on how to change this as I only looked at the examples from their page (don't have any code myself).

Answer (score 0):

The css style for invalid fields can be applied using the wrapper.

Note: this is a minimalistic answer to mark this question as solved. I will add code at a later point when I managed to get it working.